# Optimize generating html table in js

Tags: javascript, html, performance, optimization

I have script in js that generate html table with 1k elements.

Script took 2~s for generate.

How I can improve performance of it?

Here my script:

```
var
i = 0,
larr = [],
lvls = [/* 1k int's */];
while (1000!==i) {
   larr[i]=lvls[i]+' '+(++i);
}
lvls = [];

var lvl = document.getElementById('lvl');

lvl.innerHTML = `<table id="levels">
<tr>
  <th>LvL</th><th>Experience</th>
</tr>`+
larr.join(',')
.replace(/(\d+)\s(\d+),?/g, `<tr><td>$2</td><td>$1</td></tr>`)
.replace(/,/g, ``)
+`</table>`;
larr = [];
```

Here full script:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NNZabz

Ps. I want to use the only js; I don't want store result on server.

Comment: Rather than putting it directly in the dom, generate another element or document fragment, put it in their and then load that into the DOM. It'll save you a lot of rendering time.

Comment: "generate another element or document fragment" you can explain more? I not understand

Comment: Wait, I looked at your code, it won't work because you only execute the document write once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally innerHTML is very performance lacking. I would suggest generating the  elements, and appending them to a table element. I also got rid of larr completely since it looks unnecessary.

You can also put that part of the code into the while loop.

```
var i = 0,
lvls = [];
var lvl = document.getElementById('lvl');
//Make a table
var table = document.createElement('table');
table.id = 'levels';
//Add that header HTML
table.innerHTML = '<tr><th>LvL</th><th>Experience</th></tr>'

//Add that to the lvl element so it renders
lvl.appendChild(table);

var d = document.createDocumentFragment();

//Execute your level creating loop while appending children to the fragment
while (1000!==i) {
    var _tr = document.createElement('tr');
    var _t1 = document.createElement('td');
    var _t2 = document.createElement('td');
    _tr.appendChild(_t1);
    _tr.appendChild(_t2);
    _t1.innerHTML = lvls[i];
    _t1.innerHTML = ++i;
    d.appendChild(_tr);
}

//Add the document fragment to the table
table.appendChild(d);
```

Based on a quick test, this will execute in ~200ms